# Random value insertion in a table for specific range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `Orders` and a column in that table named `OrderID`. Initially the value for the `OrderID` is given manually, but now I have to change those values to random of numbers between 100 and 999.

I have nearly 600 rows... When I tried the following code it assigned a single random number to all the orders. Kindly help me on this, and explain me what's the easy and right way to solve this.

```
UPDATE Orders
 SET OrderID= RAND()*(999-100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
UPDATE Orders 
SET OrderID = ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 900) + 100
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ac86/3)**

Comment: Your code works fine but the exceeds 999... like 1061,1088 like that.

Comment: @Gopalakrishnanyadav:- Try this: `UPDATE Orders
SET OrderID = ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 999) + 100`

Comment: i tried with the new code but Same issue

Comment: @Gopalakrishnanyadav:- Try this: `UPDATE Orders SET OrderID = ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 900) + 100`

Comment: issue solved can you explain what the cause of problem by the existing codes ..

Comment: @Gopalakrishnanyadav:- The modulo operator was causing the issue. You need to get the modulo with 900. Thanks and do accept the answer if that helped you. The tick mark which turns green when clicked.